# R timeseries - identify missing observations (timestamps) and insert NAs to create time series of given length

Tags: r, time-series

I have a set of 24 grouped (hierarchical) time series supposedly running over 3 years, and I want to look at monthly sales, but it turns out that a number of them have missing observations, e.g.

```
getCounts(Shop1, ...)
2011-01 2011-02 2011-03 2011-04 2011-05 2011-06 2011-07 2011-08 2011-09 2011-10 2011-11 2011-12 2012-02 2012-03 2012-04 2012-05 2012-06 2012-07 2012-08 2012-09 2012-10 2012-11 
 10      22      10      12      36      31      25      19       7       7       7       5       1       9       9      11      10      16      25       3       2       5
```

is missing an observation for January 2012 and ends in November 2012 although it's supposed to run to December 2013.

getCounts uses the command

```
with(myDF, tapply(varName, substr(dateName, 1, 7), sum))
```

to get the monthly counts.

I want to replace the missing observations, both in the middle of the time series and at the end, with NAs, so that all my time series have the same number of observations and, if there are any "holes" they will be visible in a plot.

Can anybody help me do this?

Thanks!

Edit: My preferred output would be something like this:

```
      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2011   1  NA   2   3   4   5   6  NA   7   8   9  10
2012   2   3   4   5   6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

where each NA is replacing a missing observation.

Edit 2: getCounts() look like this:

```
getCounts <- function(dataObject, dateName, varName){ 
dataNameString <- deparse(substitute(dataObject))   
countsStr <- paste0("with(", dataNameString,", tapply(", varName, ", substr(", dateName, ", 1, 7), sum))")
counts <- eval(parse(text = countsStr))
return(counts)
}
```

And here's the dput:

```
structure(c(10, 22, 10, 12, 36, 31, 25, 19, 7, 7, 7, 5, 1, 9, 
9, 11, 10, 16, 25, 3, 2, 5), .Dim = 22L, .Dimnames = list(c("2011-01", 
"2011-02", "2011-03", "2011-04", "2011-05", "2011-06", "2011-07", 
"2011-08", "2011-09", "2011-10", "2011-11", "2011-12", "2012-02", 
"2012-03", "2012-04", "2012-05", "2012-06", "2012-07", "2012-08", 
"2012-09", "2012-10", "2012-11")))
```

Comment: How will your desired output will look like. It is not clear if you want to modify the `getCounts` output or the actual data.

Comment: It's not important what I have to modify as long as I get the correct output.

Comment: Can you provide the `dput` of `getCounts(Shop1, ...)`? Is it just a named vector?

Comment: Save `x <- getCounts(Shop1, ...)` and the do `dput(x)`

Comment: I put the function `getCounts()` in the edit. The output from `getCounts()` looks like the first output I provided, including time stamps. I want it to replace in missing observations in the middle (such as `"2012-01"`) with `NA`and also add `NAs`at the end until the desired length (here, 36). I don't know how to find the missing observations in the middle and replace them with `NA` - apart form doing it manually, which I don't think is feasible :)

Comment: See my answer. The solution is quite simple when you put it in the correct format. Though I wonder if instead of your `getCounts` you would just do `table(Shop1)`? Wouldn't that give you the same output?

Comment: If I try to table it, I get another data frame so large that it maxes out the console's print function. My data is a little more complicated than just dates an numbers, which is why I use getCounts().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
df <- data.frame(Year = substr(names(x), 1, 4),
                 Month = factor(month.abb[as.numeric(substr(names(x), 6, 7))], 
                         levels = month.abb),
                 Value = x)

library(tidyr)
spread(df, Month, Value)
#   Year Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
# 1 2011  10  22  10  12  36  31  25  19   7   7   7   5
# 2 2012  NA   1   9   9  11  10  16  25   3   2   5  NA
```

---

**Data**

```
x <- structure(c(10, 22, 10, 12, 36, 31, 25, 19, 7, 7, 7, 5, 1, 9, 
                 9, 11, 10, 16, 25, 3, 2, 5), .Dim = 22L, .Dimnames = list(c("2011-01", 
                 "2011-02", "2011-03", "2011-04", "2011-05", "2011-06", "2011-07", 
                 "2011-08", "2011-09", "2011-10", "2011-11", "2011-12", "2012-02", 
                 "2012-03", "2012-04", "2012-05", "2012-06", "2012-07", "2012-08", 
                 "2012-09", "2012-10", "2012-11")))
```

Comment: Your solution works, but in order to do further analysis (using the hts package) I also need the data as a vector, not necessarily with the time stamps, so that I can create one big ts matrix out of them. I'm sorry that I wasn't clear about this. Is there a way to extract the counts (with NAs) from that output, or is it better to do something else entirely?

Comment: What do you mean a vector? Do you mean a matrix? you can use `as.matrix` on the result

Comment: `as.matrix()`returns a matrix of string values, including the years `"2011"` and `"2012"`. I just want the counts for each month.

Comment: I don't know what's your desired output. Does `spread(df, Year, Value)[-1]` help?

Comment: If I use  `as.numeric(as.matrix(spread(df, Month, Value)))[3:26]`, then I get the vector of monthly values. Using `as.numeric(as.matrix(spread(df, Year, Value)[-1]))` works, too, and with that I don't need to remove the first two entries from the resulting vector.

Comment: These two options give you the results in different order. You need to decide what's the order you want it

Comment: Oh, you're right! Thanks for pointing that out. The one that gives me the correct output is this one `as.numeric(as.matrix(spread(df, Year, Value)[-1]))`

Comment: You can simplify it to just `unlist(spread(df, Year, Value)[-1])` and get a named numeric vector.